# COALESCE: SQL Server vs Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, null, coalesce

I have following script:

```
SELECT 1 
FROM Table t
WHERE COALESCE(NULL, t.ID) = NULL;
```

`t` is empty. The query returns `1` for Oracle and it returns nothing for SQL Server.

What is an output of `COALESCE` operation for SQL Server? Can we fix this code to behave for both DB in the same way?

Comment: It's impossible that Oracle returns `1` if the table is empty.

Comment: Not true regarding Oracle. Your query will return no rows in ANY database product that uses SQL (Oracle, SQL Server, and **all** other SQL databases), regardless of whether `t` is empty or not. Because nothing is ever **equal** to `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the point of having `colaesce` here as your first argument is `NULL`.
Just do this:

```
SELECT 1 
FROM Table t
where t.ID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the Coalesce function. If the t table is empty then no rows will be found and returned by SQL Server.